# Python, Panda.read_excel Problem reading multiple sets of Data from one sheet

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have an Excel sheet with two sets of data (picture). I want to plot those with matplotlib in Python and import them with pandas. I narrowed down my script to make it quicker to read.

### script:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

Tabelle = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\alexk\\Dropbox\\WW\\WW Master\\1. Semester\\WW2\\WW2 Kernfachpraktikum\\KFP2\\Ergebnisse.xlsx","Tabelle1")

x = Tabelle["Number1"]
y = Tabelle["Value1"]
x2=Tabelle["Number2"]
y2=Tabelle["Value2"]

plt.bar(x, y)
plt.bar(x2,y2)

plt.show()
```

### End of script.

In the script it's possible to plot x and y when x2 and y2 are hashtagged out. When I want to read/plot/whatever x2 and y2 I get an error.

### Error code:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\alexk\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3078, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Number2'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/alexk/PycharmProjects/Vickers.py", line 8, in <module>
    x2=Tabelle["Number2"]
  File "C:\Users\alexk\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2688, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_column(key)
  File "C:\Users\alexk\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 2695, in _getitem_column
    return self._get_item_cache(key)
  File "C:\Users\alexk\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2489, in _get_item_cache
    values = self._data.get(item)
  File "C:\Users\alexk\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals.py", line 4115, in get
    loc = self.items.get_loc(item)
  File "C:\Users\alexk\PycharmProjects\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3080, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 140, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 162, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1492, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Number2'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

### End of error code.

With other excel sheets this process worked fine. What am I missing? Does it have something to do with the excel sheet?

[image]

Comment: In your code, you reference the column name as x2=Tabelle["Number2"] but the column name in the excel sheet appears to have a space "Number 2".

Comment: Hey man, yeah, that was the case here. I changed the name from "Probendicke [mm]" to "Number2" for the Question here. It didn't work initially. Can't i use these brackets "[mm]" in the string for the location of the data?